# How can I let users customize background images?

Tags: javascript, css, image, background, skinning

Many sites these days have 'theming' functionality, when user is able to customize the pages' look. Sometimes it's only a fixed set of themes, but sometimes people are free to choose any style they want - for example, they can set up any color of the pages' background.

I want to go a step further - and let them choose the background *image* as well. The flow is very simple: user uploads a file (via `<input type="file" />`), then this file becomes a background image - but only for this user.

I can't find anything about this functionality online, though, and I have no clue about what to do.

Something else I was thinking was that, if a user selects a background, maybe I could use HTML5 `localstorage` to make that background come up every-time that visitor visits the page.

Comment: Please describe you question, so people can actualy understand you

Comment: How many users you expect to get? Will you allow changing these backgrounds? )

Comment: You haven't even [tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Upvoted this, because it actually can be a rather interesting task, if only client-side is involved. ) With server-side it's trivial, but again, nothing about server-side is mentioned... yet.

Comment: Can I know what the problem with this question is? I got a question ban because of this. Why are there so many down votes?

Comment: @DaKoder I've edited this question to make it a bit clearer, but as for me, even in its past form, it was understandable (and fresh) enough. Then again, the SO community thought different.

Comment: Let's be clear, your question before the edits wasn't suited for [tag:so] that's why I believe it was closed. It was full of "I want"s and none "I've tried"s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof of concept (mostly based on the code given at [MDN FileReader doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) + [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344526/setting-css-background-to-an-image-in-local-storage)):

**HTML**:

```
<input id="test" type="file" onchange="loadImageFile(this)" />
```

**JS**: *no wrap (head) mode*

```
$(switchBackground);
var oFReader = new FileReader(),
    rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    localStorage.setItem('b', oFREvent.target.result);
    switchBackground();
};

function switchBackground() {
  var backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem('b');
  if (backgroundImage) {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')');    
  } 
}

function loadImageFile(testEl) {
  if (! testEl.files.length) { return; }
  var oFile = testEl.files[0];
  if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
```

And here's a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N7KfQ/4/), checked in latest Firefox and Chrome versions. Looks to work OK, at least. )

Comment: One question: How can I let users remove the background image from their localstorage, setting the background to none?

Comment: Use `localStorage.removeItem` to delete the image, add another branch to `switchBackground()` (so that if `backgroundImage` is empty, `background-image` is reset to `none`).

Comment: @raina770w Can you make a JS Fiddle for that?

Comment: @DaKoder [Done](http://jsfiddle.net/N7KfQ/5/). But tell me, didn't I describe the approach in such details that it's easily transformed into a code? )

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick solution to this problem.

custom-background.js is a lightweight jQuery plugin to allow users change the website’s default background and saves the background selected to local storage. This plugin can easily be added to any website or web app without any compromise on website's performance.

you can download it from here and check the code
https://github.com/CybrSys/custom-background.js