# How can I let users browse there computer to choose a background image in HTML JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to allow users to browse their documents and choose a picture to set as a background image. I have already found out how a user can change the background image using a URL. Please find the demo below:

> DEMO: http://goo.gl/253IN
>
> Username: demo
>
> Password: demo1

I dont know how to get it to work with the

> File Field

I have found the following [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/N7KfQ/4/) which I would like to use. Found question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678207/how-can-i-let-users-customize-background-images)

JavaScript:

```
$(switchBackground);
var oFReader = new FileReader(),
    rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    localStorage.setItem('b', oFREvent.target.result);
    switchBackground();
};

function switchBackground() {
  $('body').css('background-image', "url(" + localStorage.getItem('b') + ')');    
}

function loadImageFile(testEl) {
  if (! testEl.files.length) { return; }
  var oFile = testEl.files[0];
  if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="test" type="file" onchange="loadImageFile(this)" />
```

However I cant get it to work with my current code (Please refer to demo)

Thanks in advance

PS I am not an expert (yet :D) on HTML and Javascrpit so I will not be able to understand really complex code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you cannot use the `file` input in this way. JavaScript does not have access to the users direct machine for security reasons. This input simply allows a file to be passed across the web stream in the body of an HTTP `POST` request.

To accomplish what you are wanting, you would have to upload the file **server side** using a server side language such as `PHP` or `ASP.NET`. You could then save it off and store it, allowing it to be displayed as the users background whenever they visited.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help, you explained that really well!

Comment: @GioL No problem buddy. Glad I could assist. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

not impossible at all!

you can actually add this functionality to you website using this plugin

https://github.com/CybrSys/custom-background.js